# Why I get error convert from char to char?

Tags: c++

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool funkcja (char * a[3][7], char * b[7]);

int main()
{

    char T[3][7]={{'A', 'L', 'A', 'M','A', 'k', 'o'},
            {'M', 'A','M','K','O','T','A'},
            {'T', 'E','Q','U','I','L','A'}};

    char tab[7]={ 'A', 'L', 'A', 'M','A', 'k', 'o' }; 

    cout<<funkcja(T, tab)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

bool funkcja (char * a[3][7], char * b[7])
{
    int licznik=0;

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<7;j++)
        {
                if (a[i][j]==b[j])
                {
                    licznik++;
                    if (licznik==7) return true;
                }
                else {
                    licznik=0;
                }
        }
        licznik=0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And when I'm trying to build this i get :

```
[Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[7]' to 'char* (*)[7]' for argument '1' to 'bool funkcja(char* (*)[7], char**)'
```

Comment: Remove the `*` from each one of the arguments that you are passing to this function.

Comment: Your `funkcja` function expects a 2D array of `char*`'s. You are trying to give it a 2D array of `char`'s. This conversion from `char` to `char*` is not allowed.

Comment: On a side note, it's an extremely bad style to give non-English names to entities in your code. I recommend getting rid of that habit sooner rather than later.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Not really, it's not "extremely bad style".

Answer (score 6):

Your function definition is not correct. You need to change:

```
bool funkcja (char * a[3][7], char * b[7])
```

to:

```
bool funkcja (char a[3][7], char b[7])
```

Note that you can omit the first array dimension, so this can be reduced to:

```
bool funkcja (char a[][7], char b[])
```

Comment: OP will have the same problem with the second parameter no?

Comment: Mistake in the second paramter.

Answer (score 2):

Your `funkcja` accepts two arrays of **pointers**, yet you are passing it the arrays of chars.

You should change your signature to:

```
bool funkcja (char a[][7], char b[]);
```

Comment: `char a[3][]` would be an array of three elements, each element having type `char []`, but that isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch between passed arguments and types of parameters in your `funkcja`. That was explained in other answers. In addition you can also pass arrays by reference, and the easiest way is to use templates. This way you can also pass their sizes at compile time.:

[[live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7f4c754f448c3e4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N, int M>
bool funkcja (char (&a)[N][M], char (&b)[M]);

int main()
{

    char T[3][7]={{'A', 'L', 'A', 'M','A', 'k', 'o'},
            {'M', 'A','M','K','O','T','A'},
            {'T', 'E','Q','U','I','L','A'}};

    char tab[7]={ 'A', 'L', 'A', 'M','A', 'k', 'o' }; 

    cout<<funkcja(T, tab)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

template<int N, int M>
bool funkcja (char (&a)[N][M], char (&b)[M])
{
    int licznik=0;

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<M;j++)
        {
                if (a[i][j]==b[j])
                {
                    licznik++;
                    if (licznik==M) return true;
                }
                else {
                    licznik=0;
                }
        }
        licznik=0;
    }
    return false;
}
```